# How to use vuejs with laravel after removing public from laravel Url?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have removed `public` from my Laravel project url. But now my Vue.js is not working.

If I remove `public` from `src` file it's not recognizing that project has Vue.js, but if I add `public` it's recognizing that this project has Vue.js. But it's not showing that component on my Blade page, instead of it it's giving me this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <app-some> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

My Blade file:

```
<div id="app">
  <app-some> </app-some>
</div>
<script src="{{asset('public/js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

`app.js` file:

```
Vue.component('appSome', require('./components/some.vue').default);
```

Comment: try importing this way -> <script src="/project_folder_name/public/js/app.js">

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

"[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

It occurs when components are not registered within the "app.js" file. In the Vue instance, try adding this

```
new Vue({
    components: {
        appSome: some
    }
});
```

Of course you also have to import the component.

Comment: i am trying to use it with laravel and it's the first vuepage i want to add on blade. as you can see i have register the component in app.js

Comment: if you are using public directory, then just use

    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" /> OR    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>. Laravel will automatically look into the public directory.